# Set Custom Key Binding to Particular Composite or Section in a View

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have created my own method which get called while pressing Ctrl + C to copy selected row and paste there. But above this tableviewer's composite , i have another composite where I have text box.

Problem : if i try to copy text which is in textbox , it doesn't copy and hence it won't be pasted as I have used method activateHandler where I have written my own logic to copy table row.

I want to make it limited to particular table composite and can use default copy and paste in TextBox Composite.

Comment: A view (or editor) is the smallest scope for a key binding. So you either make your handler deal with the different controls in your view or perhaps use a key listener on the table.

Comment: Is it possible to deactivate custom key bindings and activate default copy and paste handler on focus of textBox ?

Comment: Thanks Greg. It's resolved setting key listener to table viewer.